# How to iterate over components inside components in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have my products components which simply display  products, price and description

```
const Product = (props) =>{
    return(
        <div>
            <p>Price: {props.price} </p>
            <p>Name: {props.name}</p>
            <p>Description: {props.desc}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Which is rendered by the App component which loops thru the data in productsData and renders a product component for each index in the array.

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render() { 
    const products = productsData.map(product => {
      return <Product key={product.id} price={product.price}
      name={product.name} desc={product.description}   />
    })
    return (
      <div>
          {products}
      </div>
    );


  }
}
```

However, for the sake of learning purposes, I am trying to figure out how I am able to loop thru this array of products components  (rendered in App) to only display, for example, prices that are greater than 10 or descriptions that are longer than 10 characters, for example.

productsData looks something like this

```
const productsData = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "Pencil",
        price: 1,
        description: "Perfect for those who can't remember things! 5/5 Highly recommend."
    },
```

I am assuming I need to use the .filter method inside the products component, but I can't seem to figure out where. I keep getting errors or undefined. 
Could someone clear this up, how one would iterate thru components nested inside other components?

Comment: It is possible to chain functions like filter and map.
So I would filter first then map. So for example `...products = productsData.filter(({ price, description }) => price > 10 && description.length > 10).map(product ...`

Comment: it's so obvious now! yes!  I think I was over thinking it, thinking I had to put some condition in the component itself

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 const products = productsData.filter(product => (
  product.price > 10 || product.description.length > 10
)).map(p => (
   <Product key={p.id} price={p.price}
     name={p.name} desc={p.description}   
    />
))
```

`Chaining` methods `filter` with `map` allows you get the desired result.

Read more here about `filter`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: totally forgot about that chaining methods! for some reason I'm thinking I had to put a condition in component itself.

Comment: @Jesse mark this as the correct answer if it helped you, might help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition in `.map`, if condition matches then return the `Product` else return `null`.

```
const products = productsData.map((product) => {
  if (product.price > 10 || product.description.length > 10)
    return (
      <Product
        key={product.id}
        price={product.price}
        name={product.name}
        desc={product.description}
      />
    );
  return null;
});
```